# Events pages that are linked to venues crash when the venue entry is disabled

Tags: entries, relations

I have 2 channels, "events" and "venues". Using the entries fieldtype in the "event" entry a "venue" where it takes place is selected. However, if the venue entry is disabled, rather than the event not showing, a fatal error kills my page.

Is there a way of somehow querying events that doesn't return entries linked to disabled venues? I'm guessing doing something with relatedTo but not sure how to go about it.

```
{% set qDisplay = craft.request.getParam('display') %}
{% set qFilter = craft.request.getParam('filter') %}

{% if qDisplay == 'all' %}

    {% paginate craft.entries.section('events').status('live,pending').order('postDate asc') as entries %}

{% elseif qDisplay == 'month' and qFilter != null %}

    {% set startDate = now | date_modify('first day of ' ~ qFilter) %}
    {% set endDate = startDate | date_modify('+ 1 month') %}
    {% set entries = craft.entries.section('events').postDate('>= ' ~ startDate).expiryDate('< ' ~ endDate).status('live,pending,expired').order('postDate asc') %}

{% elseif qDisplay == 'venue' and qFilter != null %}

    {% set entries = craft.entries.section('events').relatedTo(qFilter).status('live,pending').order('postDate asc') %}

{% else %}

    {% paginate craft.entries.section('events').status('live,pending').order('postDate asc') as entries %}
    {# set entries = craft.entries.section('events').status('live,pending').limit(6).order('postDate asc') #}

{% endif %}
```

Comment: What's the fatal error?  Can you share the code you're using?

Comment: Updated with code example. When I say "fatal error" I just mean a twig error that kills the page. Its just because it expects some variables but can't get them from a null value.

Comment: Do you have any idea at which line the 'fatal error' is triggered? And do you have devMode enabled? This should give you some debug.

Comment: There's no mystery really, I'm just trying to understand how to write a entry query like: get * events where event.status = live && event.venue.status = live.